# div won't float next to preceding non-floating div

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I was fiddling around with CSS and floating the other day and stumbled upon an odd behavior (frankly I'm surprised I hadn't encountered it before). I was puzzled as to the reason for it (as well as to why I didn't already know...).

If you have a div (let's call him Bob) and you try to float him next to another div (Jimmy), it only works if

1. Jimmy is floated too
2. Jimmy comes after Bob

So if we have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="one">Main Content 1</div>
    <div id="two">Sidebar 1</div>
</div>
```

with

```css
.container { 
    overflow:hidden; /* this essentially clears the floats. You could remove it and add a clearfloat div instead */
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#one {
    background-color:red;
    margin-right:50px;
}
#two {
    width:50px;
    float:right;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

we get;
[image]
but if we just swap `#one` and `#two`, keeping the same CSS:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="two">Sidebar 2</div>
    <div id="one">Main Content 2</div>
</div>
```

we get:
[image]

Why? I'm sure it's something simple (which makes me feel stupid) related to the box model and the definition of float, but what?

You can fiddle with it [here](http://jsbin.com/ukitex/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

First remember that floated elements are not part of the *normal flow*. The rest is in the following spec:

> A floated box is shifted to the left
>   or right until its outer edge touches
>   the containing block edge or the outer
>   edge of another float. If there is a
>   line box, the outer top of the floated
>   box is aligned with the top of the
>   current line box.

Basically your second example pulls `div#two` out of the document flow and shifts it to the right until it touches the outer edge of its sibling, `div#one`. Since it has `margin: 50px;`, there's enough room for `div#two` to fit.

Your first example, `div#one` has already *cleared* that *line* as a block level element and therefore `div#two` is floated right and *aligned with the top of the current line*.

Read more from the [W3C CSS2.1 Specification on Floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats)

Comment: Reassigning an accepted answer due to an edit is not cool, friend.

Comment: @AlienWebguy, my edit really only added explanation of the first example. The original answer explained why the second example works, which was the main question. To be fair, I was also the first answer. Nonetheless, +1 to you.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the `margin-right:50px;` it should make more sense to you :)

A block element by definition takes up the full width of the parent container. Even if you give it a defined width, that's only a visual representation of the calculated width and does not affect the box model.

Floating an element does exactly that, but it floats at it's first available floatable space in the parent element. In example one, that's below the first block element. In example two, it's at the top.

If you want to achieve example 2's result in example 1, simply add `float:left;` to #one.

Comment: oh, *DUH* - I guess I'd set up a sort of mental mind-block to not realize that, lol. Thanks.

Comment: +1 "A block element by definition takes up the full width of the parent container. Even if you give it a defined width"